# Overlay non transparent Pixels in iOS Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is there any way on the iOS SDK to overlay the non-transparent pixels in an image with colored pixels?

---

Thanks very much to both who answered.

The final solution I implemented used the code mentioned in the accepted answer within the drawRect method of a subclassed UIView, I used the following code to overlay the color:

```
CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents([UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0 alpha:1].CGColor));

CGContextFillRect(context, area);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are probably looking for the blend mode **kCGBlendModeSourceAtop**. First, draw the UIImage into your view. Then obtain the current graphics context with

```
CGContext currentCtx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

Then save the context state, and set the blend mode:

```
CGContextSaveGState(currentCtx);
CGContextSetBlendMode(currentCtx, kCGBlendModeSourceAtop);
```

Then you can draw whatever you want to be overlaid over the opaque pixels of the UIImage. Afterward, just reset the context state:

```
CGContextRestoreGState(currentCtx);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify how something is drawn using the blend mode. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CGBlendMode for a full list of the blend modes supported by Core Graphics on iOS. From your description, I think you would be interested in either [kCGBlendModeSourceIn](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCGBlendModeSourceIn), which draws the new content using the old content's alpha value as a mask, or [kCGBlendModeSourceAtop](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCGBlendModeSourceAtop), which draws the new content using the old content's alpha as a mask on top of the old content using the new content's alpha value as a mask. You can set the blend mode for all drawing using `CGContextSetBlendMode`, or you can draw a UIImage with a certain blend mode using `-[UIImage drawAtPoint:blendMode:alpha:]`.