# How to add an overlay layer to a UIImageView but not on the transparent part of the image?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, layer

I have this `UIImageView`:

```
self.princessImageView.image = UIImage(named: "princess")!
```

[image]

Now I am trying to add a coloured layer with an alpha of 0.3 on this image. I tried this:

```
let overlayView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                               y: 0,
                                               width: self.princessImageView.frame.size.width,
                                               height: self.princessImageView.frame.size.height))
overlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
self.princessImageView.addSubview(overlayView)
```

But I'm getting this result.

[image]

I understand that of course it's because I'm setting an overlay on the whole view. Is there any way so I can set the overlay only on the non-transparent part of the image ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to play with blending modes for that.

Apple documentation : [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgblendmode)

Some relevant stuff which might help : [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559841/overlay-non-transparent-pixels-in-ios-cocoa)
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823493/how-to-use-a-uiimage-as-a-mask-over-a-color-in-objective-c)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Got it working with this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42353385/2885727